# Vectorized usage of difflib.SequenceMatcher() for efficient processing

Tags: python, difflib

I have a list  of sentences in variable `sample` and an in variable `strings_to_match` , my aim is to see if there is similarity between each sentence in order. i.e get the similarity score between `sample[0]` and `strings_to_match[0]` until each of the sentence in both the list.

```
sample = ['Mary had a little lamb' , 
           'Jack went up the hill' , 
           'Jill followed suit' ,    
           'i woke up suddenly' ,
           'it was a really bad dream']

strings_to_match = ['Mary had a litle lamb' , 
           'Jack went to the hill' , 
           'Jill folowed suit' ,    
           'i woke up suddenly' ,
           'it was a really bad dreem']
```

One way of doing this is to

```
scores = [difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, sample[i], strings_to_match[i]).ratio() for i in range(len(sample)]
```

but, instead of doing this looping, is there any other efficient vectorized way of getting this done?